# Which parameter is used for authentication in LDAP

Tags: ldap

In case of LDAP authenticaion, what are the **parameters** that are generally used for **authentication**. I guess using DN would be a headache for users logging in via ldap because it is too large to remember.
How is the option of using *uid* or *sAMAccountName* for authentication where in my implementation, I retrieve the dn of the corresponding uid or sAMAccountName and proceed to authentication.

Am I going the right track?

Answer (score 10):

In LDAP, a *connection* or *session* can be authenticated. When an LDAP client makes a new connection to an LDAP directory server, the connection has an authorization state of *anonymous*. The LDAP client can request that the authorization state be changed by using the BIND request.

A BIND request has two forms: simple and SASL. Simple uses a distinguished name and a password, SASL uses one of a choice of *mechanisms*, for example, PLAIN, LOGIN, CRAM-MD5, DIGEST-MD5, GSSAPI, and EXTERNAL - all of which except for GSSAPI and EXTERNAL are too weak to use in production scenarios or mission-critical areas.

To Use the simple BIND, construct a BIND request and transmit it to the LDAP directory server. The LDAP directory server will respond with a BIND response in which is contained a result code. The result code is an integer, anything other zero  indicates that the BIND request failed. If the result code is zero, the BIND request succeeded and the session authorization state has been changed to  that of the distinguished name used in the BIND request.

Each subsequent BIND request on the same connection/session causes the authorization state to be set to *anonymous* and each successive successful BIND request on the same connection/session causes the authorization state to be set to the authorization state associated with the authentication ID, which is the distinguished name in the case of the simple BIND, but might be something else entirely where SASL is used - modern professional quality servers can map the incoming names to different DNs.

Whichever language is used, construct a BIND request, transmit it to the server, and interpret the response.

Update:

If the distinguished name is not known, or is too cumbersome (often the case with web application users who don't know how they are authenticated and would not care if they did know), the LDAP application should search the directory for the user. A successful search response always contains the distinguished name, which is then used in a simple BIND.

The search contains at a minimum, the following:

- base object: a distinguished name superior to the user, for example, `dc=example,dc=com`
- a scope: base level, one level below base, or subtree below base. For example, if users are located subordinate to `ou=people,dc=example,dc=com`, use base object `ou=people,dc=example,dc=com` and a scope of `one-level`. These search parameters find entries like: `uid=user1,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com`
- a filter: narrows down the possible search results returned to the client, for example `(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)`
- a list of requested attributes: the attributes from an entry to return to the client. In this case, use `1.1`, which means *no attributes* and returns on the DN (distinguished name), which is all that is required for the simple BIND.

#### see also

the links in the about section [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/810802/terry-gardner)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Suppose I have a web application which supports login via ldap. For using the application he needs to log in to my application. If he is using ldap authentication, he will need  to pass ldap sever binding. So I ask for his bind DN and bindPWD and try to bind to the ldap server. IF bind is successful, he gets authenticated else not. But the problem here is that using the DN as username is a bit hard for the user, so what can be used as a option for that. I can repeat if i am not clear :)

Answer (score 6):

LDAP servers only understand LDAP queries; they don't have "usernames" like you and I are used to.

For LDAP, to authenticate someone, you need to send a *distinguished name* of that person's (or entity's) entry in LDAP; along with their password.

Since you mentioned *sAMAccountName* I am assuming you are working with Active Directory. Active Directory allows anonymous binds - this means you can connect to it without providing any credentials; but cannot do any lookups without providing credentials.

If you are using `python-ldap` and Cython (and not IronPython which has access to the various .NET APIs that make this process very easy); then you follow these steps.

Typically you use a pre-set user that has appropriate rights to the tree, and connect to the directory with that user *first*, and then use that user's access for the rest of the authentication process; which generally goes like this:

1. Connect to AD with the pre-set user.
2. Query active directory with the pre-set user's credentials and search for the distinguished name based on the *sAMAccountName* that the user will enter as their "username" in your form.
3. Attempt to connect again to Active Directory using the distinguished name from step 2, and the password that the user entered in their form.
4. If this connection is successful, then the user is authenticated.

So you need two main things:

1. The login attribute (this is the "username" that LDAP understands)
2. A LDAP query that fetches information for your users

Following is some rough code that can do this for you:

```
AD_USER = 'your super user'
AD_PASSWORD = 'your super user password'

AD_BIND_ATTR = 'userPrincipalName' # this is the "login" for AD
AD_URL = "ldap://your-ad-server"
AD_DN = "DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM"
AD_LOGIN_ATTR = 'sAMAccountName' # this is what you user will enter in the form
                                 # as their "login" name,
                                 # this is what they use to login to Windows

# A listing of attributes you want to fetch for the user
AD_ATTR_SEARCH = ['cn',
                  'userPrincipalName',
                  'distinguishedName',
                  'mail',
                  'telephoneNumber','sAMAccountName']

def _getbinduser(user):
    """ This method returns the bind user string for the user"""
    user_dn = AD_DN
    login_attr = '(%s=%s)' % (AD_LOGIN_ATTR,user)
    attr_search = AD_ATTR_SEARCH

    conn = ldap.initialize(AD_URL)
    conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS,0)
    conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
    try:
        conn.bind(AD_USER,AD_PASSWORD)
        conn.result()
    except:
        exceptionType, exceptionValue, exceptionTraceback = sys.exc_info()
        # Exit the script and print an error telling what happened.
        sys.exit("LDAP Error (Bind Super User)\n ->%s" % exceptionValue)
    try:
        result = conn.search_s(user_dn,
                               ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
                               login_attr, attr_search)
    except:
        exceptionType, exceptionValue, exceptionTraceback = sys.exc_info()
        # Exit the script and print an error telling what happened.
        sys.exit("LDAP Error (Search)\n ->%s" % exceptionValue)

    # Return the user's entry from AD, which includes
    # their 'distinguished name'
    # we use this to authenticate the credentials the
    # user has entered in the form
    return result[0][1]

def authenticate(user,password):

    bind_attr = AD_BIND_ATTR
    user_dn = AD_DN
    login_attr = '(%s=%s)' % (AD_LOGIN_ATTR,user)
    data = _getbinduser(user)

    if len(data) == 1:
        return None

    # Information we want to return from the directory
    # for each user, season to taste.

    info = {}
    info['name'] = data['cn'][0]
    info['email'] = data['mail'][0]
    try:
        info['phone'] = data['telephoneNumber'][0]
    except KeyError:
        info['phone'] = 'Not Available'

    conn = ldap.initialize(Config.AD_URL)
    conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS,0)
    conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)

    try:
        # Now we have the "bind attribute" (LDAP username) for our user
        # we try and connect to see if LDAP will authenticate
        conn.bind(data[bind_attr][0],password)
        conn.search(user_dn,ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,login_attr,None)
        conn.result()
        return info
    except (ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS,ldap.OPERATIONS_ERROR):
        return None
```

Comment: The distinguished name is not used in some SASL mechanisms. The LDAP client can use the form `u:username`.

Comment: Unfortunately AD has its own unique "perks" and one of them is this dn business. I have learned that if it works with AD, don't question the how and why just let it be.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understood the process, just one or two confusions. The lines :: conn.bind(data[bind_attr][0],password) means we are binding using userPrincipalName here, it would have been perfectly same if we had extracted the DN to bind isnt it. And what is the equivalent to "sAMAccountName" in linux. Is it "uid".

Comment: 'sAMAccountName' is something that active directory uses. So if you are running the script on Linux, authenticating users against Active Directory, then it will be the same. If you are activating it against some other LDAP directory; then you need to figure that out based on the directory that is being used to authenticate users.

Comment: Yes I meant authenticating against another LDAP directory, but I got the point. Thanks very much for the help. Now I am confident on my implementations :)

Comment: One more question, is userPrincipalName and (uid@domain or sAMAccountName@domain) same?

Answer (score 0):

One small expansion on Terry's excellent comment. If you store all your users in the same part of the DIT, and use the same attribute to identify them, you can programmatically construct the DN, rather than searching for it.

Comment: you should add this as a comment to Terry's answer